# VMware OS X guests stuck at 3M video memory

Tags: macos, graphics-card, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

On a `Windows 8.1` host, running `VMware Workstation v 12.5.1` (+ `Unlocker 208`). Following virtual machines set up: `OS X 10.8` thru `10.11`, `macOS Sierra`.

All but `10.9` and `10.12` show within the guests `3M` of video memory. It also happens that all these have very slow performance when running (the mouse cursor lags pretty bad). `Mavericks` reports 32 MB, `Sierra` 128 and they offer "real-time" performance.

Since even `Lion` works slowly, I don't think `Beamoff` is the solution for my problem. (Changing RAM size, processing power did nothing to improve the performance.)

Configuration-wise (both from the GUI and by comparing side-by-side the `vdx` files), all machines seem to be set up the same.

[image]

Steps I tried, but didn't make a difference in the guest (memory size unchanged):

- editing the `vdx` file and specifying `svga.autodetect = "FALSE"` and `svga.vramSize = 134217728` (notice no quotes for the numeric value, otherwise I'd get a complaint that the file has been corrupted);
- clicking `Accelerate 3D graphics` then allows me to specify a custom amount of VRAM.

(FWIW, `smc.version = 0` for all machines.)

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the use of OSX on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).

Comment: I see. In my "defense", I didn't know about this aspect - plenty of similar questions not marked as such on `Superuser`. This may have been a recent change, though. Apologizing if so.

Comment: It's a highly contentious issue, tbh. Though from my own personal perspective it's the equivalent of asking for dodgy Windows serial numbers. Mac doesn't use serials - so workarounds, whilst possible, are simply not licensed.

Comment: @Tetsujin Got it, thanks for the heads-up. I appreciate it. Hope it's not bad form to have posted my answer in the mean time as well. If this will be deemed off-topic it will go away with the question itself, if not - it may help someone else. As a developer, I have only two physical Macs and testing my software on several versions is somewhat challenging. I'll check some alternatives (VMs running on those Macs?).

Comment: You can legitimately VM OS X on Mac, from 10.6 server or 10.7 'user' upwards [& no-one really supports anything earlier so should be no worry] Parallels is good, but paid, VM software. There's also VMWare Fusion, but I haven't used that in a decade, so completely out of touch with it.

Comment: @Tetsujin Excellent, thank you for pointing me in the legitimate direction.

Comment: Most welcome - wish you luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing `VMware Tools` in one of the guests affected (`El Capitan`) solved the issue.